# why can't I order vlan with subnet size=32 from web UI?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When order a vlan from web UI, I'm only offered with 2 options about subnet size = 8 or 16.

But from this API: https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/0/getItems.json
Static Public IP Addresses has 5 options: 4,6,8,16,32, and I tried to place order with size=32, and it succeed.

So is there any particular reason the web UI limits the size to 8 or 16?

Comment: This is off-topic as it is not a programming question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, I'm able to order too, sometimes the API allows to do somethings that UI doesn't. Currently, I'm investigating about this issue, if you prefer you can submit a ticket to track it. Anyway, I will let you know any news about it.

Attach in the ticket this forum.

Comment: Thanks, ticket is opened, id is: 35323423

Comment: the response from the ticket is: the limitation is for a business reason, but he does not know. I'm working on a CLI to manage the resources, I'm not sure the CLI should be aligned with the behavior from the portal.

Comment: Currently it's not possible to order VLANS through CLI, but you can order Subnets for 4 - 8 - 16 and 32 IPv4